Watercooling start
I am planning to build a  PC with 3 AMD Radeon VII GPUs cooled via custom Bykski waterblocks. I also want to include an AMD CPU, which will also be water-cooled. I'm looking for recommendations on the following:

Motherboard: The ideal motherboard to support 3 GPUs and an AMD CPU.
Cooling setup: What components (pump, reservoir, radiators, fittings, tubing, etc.) should I use to cool both the GPUs and the CPU efficiently?
Power supply: A PSU powerful enough to handle 3 Radeon VII GPUs, the CPU, and the cooling system.
-:Case: A suitable case with enough space to accommodate the watercooling setup and the GPUs.

Please provide detailed suggestions for the specific hardware/components to make this build possible and optimal.

Radiator - something like MO-RA3 or new MO-RA4, big external radiator. For CPU+ 3 video cards - get biggest one (MO-RA IV 600) or 2 smaller ones. And use slow/quiet fans with radiator.
Main point of external radiators - heat dissipates outside computer case, so need less air flow (and less noise).
Pump - DC-5 clones.
Reservoir/Tubing/fittings - not much matter, depends of your own aesthetic preferences, as long as internal diameter of tubings/fittings no less than 10mm.
And if you want your system live long (mine works from 2013, only replaced tubings once, and few times changed cpu/gpu waterblocks when changed cpu socket/gpu generation) without problem - never use 'special fluids', especially colored ones - use distilled water only (and replace that water every 1-2 years).
